# How to force a keylock on an index constraint in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, deadlock

I am working on a deadlock issue which only happens with high volume of data. On taking the SQL Sentry logs, I can see that the lock is a keylock on a clustered index(`pk_tab12`) on an Identity column `TAB_ID` within a SP in a below line...

```
DELETE Mytable
OUTPUT deleted.field1, deleted.field2 INTO @temptabledeclaredbeforequery
WHERE TAB_ID = tabID
```

Error

> "Error: 1205, Severity:13,State:51 in proc SP_myproc at line 25:
>   Message: (Process ID 103) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim.

When I see the execution plan it is not showing any issues with this index. However I am planning to fix it by changing to non clustered index. What I would like to know is, how can I reproduce/force the deadlock in the dev environment so I can check if my fix is working?

Note: the information I have given is an example as I can't provide the actual info. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I would not expect a deadlock with this query based on the information provided but it can deadlock with other concurrent queries.

Deadlocks are difficult to repro reliably in a high-concurrency workload but I've had some success by running queries involved in the deadlock in different SSMS query windows, with execution synchronized with `sp_getapplock` so they run at nearly the same instant. Below is an example of this technique:

Get exclusive lock on session 1 to synchronize executions:

```
EXEC sp_getapplock @Resource = N'deadlock-synch', @LockMode = 'Exclusive', @LockOwner = 'Session';
GO
```

Execute query 1 on session 2, waiting for lock to be released:

```
EXEC sp_getapplock @Resource = N'deadlock-synch', @LockMode = 'Shared', @LockOwner = 'Session';
GO
--query 1 involved in deadlock
DELETE Mytable
OUTPUT 
deleted.field1
deleted.field2
INTO @temptabledeclaredbeforequery
where TAB_ID = tabID
GO
EXEC sp_releaseapplock @Resource = N'deadlock-synch', @LockOwner = 'Session';
GO
```

Execute query 2 on session 3, waiting for lock to be released:

```
EXEC sp_getapplock @Resource = N'deadlock-synch', @LockMode = 'Shared', @LockOwner = 'Session';
GO
--query 2 involved in deadlock
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
JOIN YourTable ON YourTable.Column1 = MyTable.Column1;
GO
EXEC sp_releaseapplock @Resource = N'deadlock-synch', @LockOwner = 'Session';
GO
```

Finally, release exclusive lock on session 1 to start executions:

```
EXEC sp_releaseapplock @Resource = N'deadlock-synch', @LockOwner = 'Session';
GO
```